# Why Angular ngModel with select not working

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I'm trying to bind ngModel to select in this way.

```
<select name="select1" [(ngModel)]="selectedAssessment">
  <option *ngFor="let prodFam of productFamilies" 
  [ngValue]="prodFam">{{prodFam}}</option>
```

**Component**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';
  public productFamilies: string[] = ['Collector Method', 'Manual Upload'];
  public selectedAssessment: string = 'New Assessment';
}
```

When the template gets loaded, I'm trying to display default value in select through ngModel but it's not getting displayed. What is wrong here?
[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-jzzf51)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have **`New Assessment`** in your source array, set it as follows

```
  public productFamilies: string[] = ['Collector Method', 'Manual Upload','New Assessment'];
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-uyscvf?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't use placeholder in default html dropdown. But you can disable first option, So it will display same as like place holder.

I had created stackblitz demo : [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hsqu2)

Comment: But how do I reset this to default again? for example, if I open a modal after selecting an option and closing the modal how do I reset to New Assessment??

Comment: Just Pass `this.selectedAssessment = '';`, I had also updated demo please check it again above Stackblitz link.